# How to get the image/file path for field type="file" using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, file, input

I have an html upload/browsing field as below

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
              function get_image_or_files_path()
              {  
                 var files = document.getElementById("selectedFile").files;
                 for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
                    console.log(files[i].name+'>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>');
              }       
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
     <input type="file" id="selectedFile" name="get_image_path" onfocusout="get_image_or_files_path()"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

So by the above javascript, i can able to get the `file/image` name, but how to get the `url/path` of the `file/image`

Comment: On the client machine, or the server?

Comment: Actually i am new to javascript/jquery, i want on the client/user machine when trying to upload a file, because i want to fetch that and show him a thumbnail of the image that he has selected before submitting to the server

Comment: You can't access the local file system.

Comment: Take a look this post.

[you can't do it][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4176605/2545964

Comment: becasue after submitting to the server, anyway we will have the image in database so simply we can display it, so when a user uploads an image, immediately i need to fetch the image path and show him it

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the full path of the file from a file input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176377/how-to-get-the-full-path-of-the-file-from-a-file-input)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Full path from file input using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489133/full-path-from-file-input-using-jquery)

Comment: but how like `jQuery-File-Upload` will generate a preview of the image ? https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: k then is there any way to generate the preview of the image, before uploading to the server, because some sites will do so right?

Comment: You can do that using the file api, in browsers that support it.

Comment: can u please provide me an example and move in a right direction to accomplish this task ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get full path of selected file on change of <input type=‘file’> using javascript, jquery-ajax?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201071/how-to-get-full-path-of-selected-file-on-change-of-input-type-file-using-jav)

Comment: The solution then, is to use canvas : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19115758/resizing-image-and-set-it-to-the-inputfile/19288727#19288727